# Achievements not show when change device language

Tags: android, google-play-games

-I have set the achievements in the developers console in two languages English (predefined) and Spanish. All achievements have translations.

-When I change the language of the device from Spanish to English, no achievement is shown. Only "No archivements for this game" is displayed.

-Once the language of device has been set in English, I have restarted the device, I have left the Play Games account and I have entered again, I have uninstalled and installed the application again. All with the same result, does not show achievements.

-Archivements are in console in test mode (ready for publish)

-In the game I have leaderboards and language (title of leaderboard) switch ok spanish/english.

-To show the achievements I use the following code:

```
 Games.getAchievementsClient(c, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(c))
                    .getAchievementsIntent()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                            c.startActivityForResult(intent, 12341);
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some versions of English in play games console, does selected English version in play console matches to device version of English?